# Confusion on Mobile App Development

Tags: html, mobile, jquery-mobile, cross-platform

After reading tons of tutorials and opinions, I'm more confused than ever on what could be a solid combination of tools to build a cross-platform client-server app, where the bulk of the cpu work is done on the server. The client just needs to push/pull data from the server on a regular interval, and display among other things a Google map with some moving markers. The logic is quite simple, but I can't really figure out the best way to do what I want, especially since I'm just an amateur.

So I've decided to set up Eclipse with PhoneGap, but looking for decent samples I found about AppLaud and AppLaudCloud. And then Sencha Touch. And then Mono (I'm familiar with .NET). And Appcelerator... I'm lost!!!

Could anyone please tell me where to start? Or better, which solution is the easiest to set up and work with while retaining flexibility?

Many thanks
Chris

Comment: A web app would probably be an easier place to start vs a native Android/iOS app. I've used jQuery Mobile with success.

Comment: Yes, I think I got that bit. What about the tools?

Comment: I just used ASP.NET MVC 3. Other than including the jQuery Mobile libraries, I didn't need any mobile-specific tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever is worth, here is what I used to build a couple of webapps successfully: Dreamweaver CS5.5 + JQuery Mobile + PhoneGap.

This solution allowed me to easily design the app's UI and at the same time write the PHP server code effortlessly. In my opinion, it's the easiest tool for a beginner as the Dreamweaver environment takes care of pretty much everything. After watching a few free tutorials about DW, I was up and running very quickly.